# What's difference between two deletion of linked-list?

Tags: c++, linked-list

I wrote two method two delete the given node, and i though they are the same. However, they give different result.

First,

```
    node *q = c->next;
    c->data = q->data;              second:  c->data = c->next->data;
    c->next = q->next;                       c->next = c->next->next;
    delete q;                                delete c->next;
```

I try the example(linked list:1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 and c==3)
the first method give the result: 1,2,4,5,6,7,8,9,10, which is what i want

but the second give:1,2,4,-572662307
I cannot understand what make difference.

Comment: In the second, you've changed `c->next` to `c->next->next`, and have lost what `c->next` previously pointed to.

Comment: Can you specifically explain what moment does c->next lost

Comment: Take out some paper and a pencil and draw what happens in each case.

Comment: i got it, i should take a break after coding all day...

Answer (score 1):

A significant difference is that after the first, `c->next` will be pointing to what used to be (before the algorithm) `c->next->next`. After the second, `c->next` will be pointing to a deleted node.

Another difference is that the first deletes what used to be `c->next` before the algorithm, while the second deletes the node that used to be `c->next->next` before the algorithm.